# Writing ID3v2 Tag parsing code, need Good examples to test

Tags: id3

I am writing software to parse ID3v2 tags in Java.  I need to find some files with good examples of the tag with lots of different frames.  Ideally the tags will contain an embedded picture because that is what is kicking my butt right now.

Does anyone know where I can find some good free (legal) ID3v2 tagged files (ID3v2.2 and ID3v2.3)?

Comment: Mind providing clarification or choosing an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the example files with a tagger by yourself. I'm the author of the Windows freeware tagger [Mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) which is able to write ID3v2.3 (UTF-16 and ISO-8859-1) and ID3v2.4 tags in UTF-8 (both along with APIC frames). You can find a list of supported frames [here](http://mp3tag.de/en/help/main_tags.html).

To create ID3v2.2 tags, I think the only program out there is iTunes which interpretes the ID3 spec in it's very own way and writes numerous iTunes specific frames that are not in the spec.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe be obvious and not what you are seeking, but what about ripping some of your legally obtained CDs and editing them using iTunes? iTunes would also allow you to add embedded picture. There are of course many open source programs that will also do this.

Comment: or Winamp, if you don't feel like installing all of Apple's cruft.

Comment: Even Winamp sneakily installs a kernel-mode driver, last time I checked :-/