# Read id3 tag from ffmpeg-converted mp3 files

Tags: php, mp3

I have the below script for reading the `id3` tag for mp3 files. I have checked manually that `id3` tags are there in mp3 files but my output always returns for a few files: 
`MP3 file does not have any ID3 tag!`

I am converting these files from ffmpeg. When I run the below code for original files, it shows the `id3` tags, but when I run the script for converted files (by ffmpeg), it is not showing any `id3` tags . I have downloaded both original and converted files and checked them and found that both files have exactly the same tags but the below code gives the error message anyway.

Here is the code:

```
 <?php
 $mp3 = "4.mp3"; //The mp3 file.

 $filesize = filesize($mp3);
 $file = fopen("4.mp3", "r");

 fseek($file, -128, SEEK_END); // It reads the 

 $tag = fread($file, 3);

 if($tag == "TAG")
 {
     $data["title"] = trim(fread($file, 30));

     $data["artist"] = trim(fread($file, 30));

     $data["album"] = trim(fread($file, 30));

     $data["year"] = trim(fread($file, 4));

      $data["genre"] = trim(fread($file, 1));



   }
   else
     die("MP3 file does not have any ID3 tag!");

   fclose($file);

   while(list($key, $value) = each($data))
   {
     print("$key: $value<br>\r\n");    
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure they are ID3v1 tags, and not ID3v2 tags?  ID3v2 is completely different.

Comment: @brad they are mixed sometimes it may be 1 sometimes 2.in this case it is 2

Comment: If you want to parse ID3v2, then you need to write an ID3v2 parser!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173257/writing-id3v2-tag-parsing-code-need-good-examples-to-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires the correct `id3` version. I have solved the problem with this code:

```
<?

print_r( tagReader ("4.mp3") );

function tagReader($file){
  $id3v23 = array("TIT2","TALB","TPE1","TRCK","TDRC","TLEN","USLT");
  $id3v22 = array("TT2","TAL","TP1","TRK","TYE","TLE","ULT");
  $fsize = filesize($file);
  $fd = fopen($file,"r");
  $tag = fread($fd,$fsize);
  $tmp = "";
  fclose($fd);

  if (substr($tag,0,3) == "ID3") {
    $result['FileName'] = $file;
    $result['TAG'] = substr($tag,0,3);
    $result['Version'] = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($tag,3,1))).".".hexdec(bin2hex(substr($tag,4,1)));
  }

  if($result['Version'] == "4.0" || $result['Version'] == "3.0"){
    for ($i=0;$i<count($id3v23);$i++){
      if (strpos($tag,$id3v23[$i].chr(0))!= FALSE){
        $pos = strpos($tag, $id3v23[$i].chr(0));
        $len = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($tag,($pos+5),3)));
        $data = substr($tag, $pos, 9+$len);
        for ($a=0;$a<strlen($data);$a++){
          $char = substr($data,$a,1);
          if($char >= " " && $char <= "~") $tmp.=$char;
        }
        if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TIT2") $result['Title'] = substr($tmp,4);
        if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TALB") $result['Album'] = substr($tmp,4);
        if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TPE1") $result['Author'] = substr($tmp,4);
        if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TRCK") $result['Track'] = substr($tmp,4);
        if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TDRC") $result['Year'] = substr($tmp,4);
        if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TLEN") $result['Lenght'] = substr($tmp,4);
        if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "USLT") $result['Lyric'] = substr($tmp,7);
        $tmp = "";
      }
    }
  }

  if($result['Version'] == "2.0"){
    for ($i=0;$i<count($id3v22);$i++){
      if (strpos($tag,$id3v22[$i].chr(0))!= FALSE){
        $pos = strpos($tag, $id3v22[$i].chr(0));
        $len = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($tag,($pos+3),3)));
        $data = substr($tag, $pos, 6+$len);
        for ($a=0;$a<strlen($data);$a++){
          $char = substr($data,$a,1);
          if($char >= " " && $char <= "~") $tmp.=$char;
        }
        if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TT2") $result['Title'] = substr($tmp,3);
        if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TAL") $result['Album'] = substr($tmp,3);
        if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TP1") $result['Author'] = substr($tmp,3);
        if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TRK") $result['Track'] = substr($tmp,3);
        if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TYE") $result['Year'] = substr($tmp,3);
        if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TLE") $result['Lenght'] = substr($tmp,3);
        if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "ULT") $result['Lyric'] = substr($tmp,6);
        $tmp = "";
      }
    }
  }

  return $result;
}

?>
```

Comment: By the way, your code contains a typo, it's `Length`, not `Lenght`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a PECL extension that already solves parsing of ID3 data. You can read about it in the PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.id3.php.

Comment: thx for your answer can you please tell why my output is co,ing like this. Array ( [FileName] => 4.mp3 [TAG] => ID3 [Version] => 3.0 [Title] => &Bahut Khubsurat Ghazal (mr-Jatt.Com) [Album] => 1Loverz Choice (A Khubsurat Ghazal) (www.mzc.in) [Author] => DJ Badboy (mr-Jatt.Com) [Track] => (www.mzc.in) )     i ant neat output to store in database please tell how i can store each data separetly in mysql

Comment: thx for your answer can you please tell why my output is co,ing like this. Array ( [FileName] => 4.mp3 [TAG] => ID3 [Version] => 3.0 [Title] => &Bahut Khubsurat Ghazal (mr-Jatt.Com) [Album] => 1Loverz Choice (A Khubsurat Ghazal) (www.mzc.in) [Author] => DJ Badboy (mr-Jatt.Com) [Track] => (www.mzc.in) ) i ant neat output to store in database please tell how i can store each data separetly in mysql